# Create 1 video using image with length of audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create video with the length of an audio file , and 1 single image as the background for whole video.

I use following code

```
'ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -f image2 -r 24 -i subtitle.jpg  -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest video.flv';
```

But problem is processing time is too slow , and sometime video length is not same as audio length.Can some one suggest me alternative ideas.

p.s : audio length is just 3 to 8 seconds.

Below is my output

> ffmpeg version N-83443-gc03029a Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg
> developers built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libfdk_aac
> --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libgsm --enable-libxvid --disable-static --enable-shared libavutil 55. 46.100 / 55. 46.100 libavcodec 57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100 libavformat 57. 66.101
> / 57. 66.101 libavdevice 57. 2.100 / 57. 2.100 libavfilter 6. 73.100 /
> 6. 73.100 libswscale 4. 3.101 / 4. 3.101 libswresample 2. 4.100 / 2. 4.100 libpostproc 54. 2.100 / 54. 2.100 Input #0, image2, from 'subtitle/1.jpg': Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
> Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown),
> 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc [mp3 @
> 0x1013ee0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
> Input #1, mp3, from 'audio/1.mp3': Metadata: encoder : Lavf57.71.100
> Duration: 00:00:05.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s Stream #1:0:
> Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s No pixel format specified,
> yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen. Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for
> compatibility with outdated media players. [libx264 @ 0x1020600] using
> SAR=1/1 [libx264 @ 0x1020600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast
> SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX [libx264 @ 0x1020600] profile High, level 3.1
> [libx264 @ 0x1020600] 264 - core 148 r2762 90a61ec - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC
> codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html -
> options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7
> psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1
> 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2
> threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1
> interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2
> b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
> keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
> mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
> aq=1:1.00 Output #0, flv, to 'video/1.flv': Metadata: encoder :
> Lavf57.66.101 Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] /
> 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 24 fps,
> 1k tbn, 24 tbc Metadata: encoder : Lavc57.75.100 libx264 Side data:
> cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1 Stream
>
> ## 0:1: Audio: mp3 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264
>
> (libx264)) Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> [image2 @ 0x1011680] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising
> the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8) frame= 32 fps=0.0
> q=0.0 size= 0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed= 0x frame= 53 fps=
> 51 q=28.0 size= 210kB time=00:00:00.13 bitrate=13157.8kbits/s
> speed=0.126x frame= 73 fps= 47 q=28.0 size= 216kB time=00:00:00.96
> bitrate=1828.9kbits/s speed=0.622x frame= 93 fps= 45 q=28.0 size=
> 221kB time=00:00:01.79 bitrate=1009.9kbits/s speed=0.859x frame= 109
> fps= 42 q=28.0 size= 225kB time=00:00:02.45 bitrate= 750.6kbits/s
> speed=0.95x frame= 126 fps= 40 q=28.0 size= 230kB time=00:00:03.16
> bitrate= 594.3kbits/s speed=1.02x frame= 145 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=
> 235kB time=00:00:03.95 bitrate= 485.7kbits/s speed=1.09x frame= 162
> fps= 39 q=28.0 size= 239kB time=00:00:04.67 bitrate= 419.3kbits/s
> speed=1.12x frame= 181 fps= 39 q=28.0 size= 244kB time=00:00:05.46
> bitrate= 366.5kbits/s speed=1.17x frame= 193 fps= 33 q=28.0 Lsize=
> 248kB time=00:00:05.95 bitrate= 340.4kbits/s speed=1.03x video:217kB
> audio:23kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 2.834417% [libx264 @ 0x1020600] frame I:1 Avg QP:17.19
> size:212155 [libx264 @ 0x1020600] frame P:48 Avg QP:18.02 size: 140
> [libx264 @ 0x1020600] frame B:144 Avg QP:27.33 size: 43 [libx264 @
> 0x1020600] consecutive B-frames: 0.5% 0.0% 0.0% 99.5% [libx264 @
> 0x1020600] mb I I16..4: 3.1% 86.8% 10.2% [libx264 @ 0x1020600] mb P
> I16..4: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% P16..4: 1.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% skip:99.0%
> [libx264 @ 0x1020600] mb B I16..4: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% B16..8: 0.1% 0.0%
> 0.0% direct: 0.0% skip:99.8% L0: 9.1% L1:90.9% BI: 0.0% [libx264 @ 0x1020600] 8x8 transform intra:82.0% inter:55.7% [libx264 @ 0x1020600]
> coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 87.6% 80.7% 62.5% inter: 0.0% 0.2% 0.0%
> [libx264 @ 0x1020600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 76% 22% 2% 1% [libx264 @
> 0x1020600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 11% 15% 24% 7% 9% 7% 10% 6%
> 10% [libx264 @ 0x1020600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 27% 9% 7%
> 8% 6% 8% 5% 8% [libx264 @ 0x1020600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 55% 23% 14% 8%
> [libx264 @ 0x1020600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0% [libx264 @
> 0x1020600] ref P L0: 95.1% 0.1% 3.2% 1.6% [libx264 @ 0x1020600] ref B
> L0: 91.7% 3.3% 5.0% [libx264 @ 0x1020600] ref B L1: 86.1% 13.9%
> [libx264 @ 0x1020600] kb/s:223.84 0

Comment: @LordNeckbeard : I have added my output

Comment: Your console output is difficult to read without the usual line breaks. How are you verifying that the "video length is not same as audio length"?